# QGIS Field Calculator - adding up value from another layer

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, aggregation

I need to sum values from one layer over another, in a 1-n relationship, based on an attribute.

For example:

Layer 1, Column to join `name_1`, Number column to enter value `number_1`;

Layer 2, Column to join `name_2`, column from which we count the value `number_2`

If `name_1` is equal to `name_2`, we sum the `number_2` values in the `number_1` column

Comment: Are you asking how to use `sum()`?

Comment: Yes, but with date form different layers and not equal relation.

Comment: So you're asking how to access a different layer via the field calculator. I suppose there are many answered questions on this issue available.

Comment: Yes, I know how to access different layer, but I have issue with making calculation on them. If you know some thread that will explain me this. I would be glad to read it.

Answer (score 3):

I figure out it by myself. The issue was with formula that I try many times before. This time something change and it’s working properly.

```
aggregate(layer:='layer2',
          aggregate:='sum',
          expression:= "value2",
          filter:="name2"=attribute(@parent,'name1'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to GIS.SE!

To demonstrate this I set up two layers Layer 1 and Layer 2:

Layer 1 only with attribute `name_1`:

[image]

Layer 2 with attributes `name_2` and `value_2`:

[image]

Using Field Calculator create a virtual field to sum up `value_2` grouped by `name_2` (Note that sum is in the Aggregates section!):

[image]

I used decimal numbers here but that does not matter. The resulting Layer 2 looks like this:

[image]

Now you can join Layer 2 to Layer 1 using Joins-tab in the properties of Layer 1:

[image]

Set up your join like this:

[image]

You end up with a Layer 1 like this:

[image]

Note that features named `test2` and `test3` have empty sum attributes because the names are not represented in Layer 2.

Comment: Thank you very much for work you done. I know this way, but i what to do it 100% in Field Calculator.

Comment: I used first part of what you show me and I use:

attribute(get_feature( 'layer2','name2',"name1"),'layer2_sum_value')